# I need to determine the successive odd numbers whose sum is equal to n^3, for n = 1, ..., 20 (as an example 1^3 = 1; 2^3 = 3 + 5; 3^3 = 7 + 9 + 11)

Tags: c

I tried to solve it on my own way, but instead of giving me consecutive odd numbers, it gave me the result of a cubic number. How can I make so it'll give me, after the compilation, consecutive odd numbers whose sum equals to n^3(cubic number) like the examples shown above? Thanks in advance and also do not forget to explain me how you did it. Please use C, when giving a much more viable solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n, sum;

    printf("Value of n= ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int n=1; n<=20; n++)
    {
        if(n%2!=0);
    }

    printf("%d", sum=pow(n,3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, please explain in greater detail what you intend to accomplish. Also, please specify the input, intended output and actual output.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The title seems pretty clear to me, but the question itself, given the shown code, may be better phrased as something like "I have no idea how to solve this problem, can anyone give me some hints about what algorithm should I use?".

Comment: @Bob__: Ah, I understand the question now.

Comment: so basically, by compiling the code that I posted and by giving n a value, like for example 3, you'll get the result 27(3^3=27), but that's not what I'm looking for, instead I would want it to show the consecutive odd numbers whose sum will be equal to 3^3, so by compiling and putting 3 as the value of n, I would want the result to not be 27, but 7+9+11. That is not limited to only 3, it could be any number

Comment: I tried by myself, but I did not work, if you want to give me a hint or something, it'll be much appreciated, if not then ignore this post. I'm a beginner so that's why the question seems redundant, I just want to understand what I did wrong and for someone to correct me and explain the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking it like that, I tried a few numbers and found the solution in math. I guess this is not what you wanted, but it does work and consists of only odd numbers.

```
1^3=1
2^3=3+5
3^3=7+9+11
4^3=13+15+17+19
5^3=21+23+25+27+29
...

x^3=[x*(x-1)+1]+[x*(x-1)+3]+...+[x*(x-1)+2x-1]
```

for math proof, define it as a series:

```
An=x^2-x+1+2(n-1)=x^2-x+1+2n-2=x^2-x+2n-1

Sx=(A1+Ax)*x/2=[(x^2-x+1)+(x^2-x+2x-1)]*x/2=(2x^2)*x/2=x^3
```

Also, because `n(n-1)` is always even, the numbers must be odd.

to write it as code:

```
void printOddNumbers(int n)
{
    int a1 = n * (n - 1) + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d+", a1 + 2 * i);
    }
    printf("\b=%d^3=%d\n", n, n * n * n);
}
```

So the output will look like: `13+15+17+19=4^3=64`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, kind sir, I see what I've been doing wrong, I cannot believe that the whole code that I posted was wrong, I was thinking that maybe "for" and "if" and it would something related to printf

Comment: I understand what you did, but can you please explain, why do you mean by "%d+" and "\b"?

Comment: its just for the beauty of the print. `\b` is backspace so it will print, for example: `13+15+17+19=4^3=64` without + after 19.

Comment: @ArteliniusZ.: For the meaning of `"%d"`, see the [documentation on `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).  The remaining "+" ist just a literal character that is to be printed.

Comment: @RoyAvidan, do you have a facebook account or something where I could reach you?

Comment: you can reach me with mail instead royavi1403@gmail.com. I never check my facebook messages.

Answer (score -1):

So, you have an input, n, which is the number of consecutive odd numbers, which should yield a given sum as a result. So, this is how it looks alike:

> sum = k + (k + 2) + ... + (k + 2n - 2) =
>
> = n * k + 2 * (1 + 2 + ... + n - 1) =
>
> = n * k + 2 (n * (n - 1) / 2) =
>
> = n * k + n * (n - 1) =
>
> = n * (n + k - 1)

n is known, k is an unkown odd number. So, for sum = 27 and n = 3 this would mean

> 3 * (3 + k - 1) = 27
>
> 3 + k - 1 = 9
>
> k + 2 = 9
>
> k = 7

7 + 9 + 11 = 27

For sum = 125, k = 5:

> 5 * (5 + k - 1) = 125
>
> 5 + k - 1 = 25
>
> k = 21

21 + 23 + 25 + 27 + 29 = 125

So, the implementation would look like this:

```
int getK(int n, int sum) {
    int k = (sum / n) - n + 1;
    int currentSum = k;
    int result = k;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) currentSum += 2 * i + k;
    return ((currentSum == sum) && (k % 2)) ? k : 0;
}
```

Explanation: We return the smallest of the set when the problem is solvable. If it is not an odd, then we return 0 as a sign of error. Also, if the sum does not add up, then the problem is unsolvable and we return 0.

Comment: Can someone shed some light on the cause of this answer being downvoted?

Comment: Not the DV, but please note that you may have misinterpreted the problem statement. Given a value n, there *always* exists a sequence of succesive n odd numbers that sum up to n^3. Other than the method you showed, consider that n^3 = n * n^2 or the sum of n times n^2 and that you can transform each of those terms to an odd number (e.g. n=5, n^3 = 125  =  25+25+25+25+25 = (25-4)+(25-2)+25+(25+2)+(25+4) = 21+23+25+27+29 or n = 4, n^3 =64 = 16+16+16+16 = (16-3)+(16-1)+(16+1)+(16+3) = 13+15+17+19).